# My wireless router is unreachable unless I restart wpa_supplicant

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

My wireless connection stops working frequently (more specifically I am not able to ping my router after 5 to 40 minutes of use). After the connection stops working I have to restart WPA_supplicant, and then it starts working again.

I have no other problems once I am connected. I can browse the internet at normal speed.

Right now I am manually executing all commands to connect to the internet at the command line, I am restarting WPA_supplicant with wap_gui.

I have noticed that I need to wait a few seconds before I ping the wireless router after reconnecting.

My wireless card is connected through USB:  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS].

I am using the following driver (lsusb -t): Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtl8192cu

I am connecting to an ASUS RT-N12D1 router. Standard setup.

I obtained my ip address using dhcp (busybox udhcpc -i devname)

Comment: It could be heating up if it's sitting in a closet or something I would recommend moving to more clear place with proper air circulation

Comment: No, my router is sitting in the middle of the hallway

Comment: You didn't mention distro, kernel version, etc... Have you seen this? http://askubuntu.com/q/123937/457063

Comment: I'll try the proprietary driver

Comment: So 5-40 minutes randomly, probably on security key rotation for WiFi which is why you have to restart WPA_supplicant? Have you tried temporarily disabling the security on the WiFi and testing it? or trying a different security method?